# R710 - Win2003 Install - Drive Partition Issue

Tags: dell-poweredge, windows-server-2003

I installed Windows 2003 server on an R710 with RAID5.  The problem is that it started with a C: partition with drivers on it.  So - the base OS installed on Drive E (because D was taken by the DVD drive). :(

How can I correct this?  I need to get it working like normal.  I have no problem re-installing, but I could NOT delete that partition from the Windows installation.  And I couldn't seem to change the drive letter (unless I did it wrong) from Computer Management.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found this article on Microsoft that fixes the problem:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896536

KB896536